# AngularJS mustache doesn't load in IE9 unless in dev mode

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've a weird bug where AngularJS doesn't appear to parse/compile the mustache and bind it to a variable on the first loading of the site (see screenshot). The problem goes away if I enter into development mode and refresh the page; hence it becomes hard to debug since I can't see the errors.

[image]

There is a live version of the site available at http://www.notable.ac

Comment: It is very difficult to read the js source, but do you happen to have `console.log()` in your code?  IE without devmode does not have console defined, so produces error if used.

Comment: I do have console.log() defined in the code. That could be the reason why. I would assume the way around this is by checking for some Dev environment variables to enable the console.log?

Comment: console is not available in IE with dev tools disabled, you can just test if(console) { console.log('ok') }, edit: made an answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it's the console issue...

Just add a stub in the root of your JS:

```
//make sure console.log exists in ie.
window.console = window.console || {};
window.console.log = window.console.log || function(){};
```

Answer (score 1):

console is not available in IE with dev tools disabled, 
you can just test:

```
if(console && console.log) { 
  console.log('ok');
}
```

Comment: Thanks but how would you be able to read what the console output is without the devtools in IE?

Comment: why would you want to read the console output when the console is off?

Comment: Sorry I read your answer incorrectly. Your answer is valid, though I would have to go to every console.log() and condition it, which is inconvenient given how many I need to wrap it with.

Comment: ok no problem, I usually use a custom .log function and link it to the browser function is neccessary/possible to have maximum flexibility (can additionaly write to a div for example is neccesary)